# Applying squeeze theorem to a given function

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How am I supposed to squeeze a given function between two other functions while applying "squeeze theorem"?

For instance, take this example:

Q.Evaluate:
$$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right)$$

Let us say, the function inside the bracket is $g(n)$. Now how can I find two other functions that such that $f(n)≤ g(n)≤ h(n)$.

Answer to this question is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

A useful tool that is often used is that when $a\leq b$, then $\frac{1}{a} \geq \frac{1}{b}$.  So in this case $n^2\leq n^2+k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  So we have $\frac{1}{n^2} \geq \frac{1}{n^2+k}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.  That is

$g(x)= \frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+...+ \frac{n}{n^2+n} \\
\leq \frac{n}{n^2}+\frac{n}{n^2}+...+\frac{n}{n^2} \\
= \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+...+\frac{1}{n} \\
= \frac{1}{n}(1+1+...+1) \\
=\frac{1}{n}(n) \\
=1$.

For the lower bound, we'll do essentially the samething, but for each $\frac{n}{n^2+k}$, we're going to use the estimate $\frac{n}{n^2+k} \geq \frac{n}{n^2+n}$, noting that there are $n$ of them, and then take a limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: could you please explain the lower bound again? i am able to understand the expression for upper bound.

Comment: Sure!  For $1 \leq k \leq n$, we have $n^2+k \leq n^2+n$.  That implies that $\frac{1}{n^2+n} \leq \frac{1}{n^2+k}$.  So 

$g(x)=\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+n} \\
\geq \frac{n}{n^2+n}+\frac{n}{n^2+n}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+n} \\
=\frac{n}{n^2+n} \left(1+1+...+1 \right) \\
=\frac{n}{n^2+n}(n) \\
=\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}.$

So $g(x) \geq \frac{n^2}{n^2+n}$.  Taking $n \rightarrow \infty$ you get the desired lower bound. *Edit: I don't know why it formatted it weird

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the given function by simpler ones that bracket it tightly and for which you can compute the limit. In the case of

$$\frac n{n^2+k}=\frac1{n+\dfrac kn},$$ as $1\le k\le n$, we have the inequalities

$$n\le n+\frac kn\le n+1,$$

leading to

$$n\frac1{n+1}\le\sum_{k=1}^n \frac n{n^2+k}\le n\frac1n.$$

Answer (score 1):

As , $$n^2+1 \le n^2+1 \le n^2+n , \\ n^2+1 \le n^2+2 \le n^2+n, \\ n^2+1 \le n^2+3 \le n^2+n, \\ \vdots \\ n^2+1 \le n^2+n \le n^2+n $$
$\implies$
$$ \frac{1}{n^2+n} \le \frac{1}{n^2+1} \le \frac{1}{n^2+1} ,\\   \frac{1}{n^2+n} \le \frac{1}{n^2+2} \le \frac{1}{n^2+1} , \\  \frac{1}{n^2+n} \le \frac{1}{n^2+3} \le \frac{1}{n^2+1} ,\\  \vdots \\  \frac{1}{n^2+n} \le \frac{1}{n^2+n} \le \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$

(As, if $\displaystyle a\le b \le c \implies a\le b , b\le c \implies \frac{1}{b} \le \frac{1}{a} , \frac{1}{c} \le \frac{1}{b}
 \implies \frac{1}{c} \le \frac{1}{b} \le \frac{1}{a} $)

Multipling $n$ to each inequality and summing them,we have,

$$\left(\frac{n}{n^2+n}+\frac{n}{n^2+n}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right) \le \left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+\cdots +\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right) \le \left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+1}+ \cdots +\frac{n}{n^2+1} \right) $$
$\implies $
$$ \frac{n^2}{n^2+n} \le \left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+\cdots +\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right) \le \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} $$
$\implies $
$$ \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}} \le \left(\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+\cdots +\frac{n}{n^2+n}\right) \le \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}} $$

Comment: but how did you arrive at those?

Comment: $ n^2+n > n^2+ i > n^2+1 $ , for each $1\le i \le n$  do you now understand?

Comment: is this like a standard result or something?

Comment: I do some edits for you.

Comment: I have edited it to look more better.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\frac{n}{n^2+1}\ge\frac{n}{n^2+2}\geq\frac{n}{n^2+3}\geq...\geq\frac{n}{n^2+n}$ - This is true because the numerators are equal, so the greater the denominator the smaller the number.

We have $n$ elements that are being summed, so from the aforementioned conclusion we can then conclude $n\times\frac{n}{n^2+1}=\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}\geq\frac{n}{n^2+1}+\frac{n}{n^2+2}+\frac{n}{n^2+3}+...+\frac{n}{n^2+n}\geq n\times\frac{n}{n^2+n}=\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}$.
So now we bounded given sum from above by $\frac{n^2}{n^2+1}$ and from below by $\frac{n^2}{n^2+n}$. Both boundaries go to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, and therefore from the squeeze theorem we can conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k}=1$.